# After updating Google play services to 8.4.0 push notifications displayed by themselves

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

For Push notifications we are using GCM(Google Cloud Messaging). It was working fine when we used play-services:8.3.0 . We process push notifications with our own receiver. After upgrading to `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0`
Push not coming to my myGcmListenerService, instead its shown by itself in notification bar. Also it shows this error in Log 
`GcmAnalytics: Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event.`

With 8.3.0 we received push like this:

`Bundle[{gcm.notification.e=1, google.c.a.ts=234343426, gcm.notification.badge=1, gcm.notification.sound=default, gcm.notification.sound2=default, gcm.notification.body=John M @ Cords, Wires And Cable Ftu, gcm.notification.data={"name":"new_chat_message","message_id":490666,"channel_id":5366}, google.c.a.e=1, collapse_key=com.domain.app.debug}]`

With 8.4.0 pushes coming like this:

`Bundle[{notification=Bundle[{sound2=default, e=1, body=John M @ Cords, Wires And Cable Rrr, data={"name":"new_chat_message","message_id":490641,"channel_id":5366}, badge=1, sound=default}], collapse_key=com.domain.app.debug}]`

Comment: have you checked on the documentation for any breaking change between these 2 versions?

Comment: From documentation: `Notification - GCM automatically displays the message to end user devices on behalf of the client app.` and `Data - Client app is responsible for processing data messages. `. Problem is that beside Android we also need to support our IOS client, so we need Notification to be used for IOS (to handle push by system) and Data for Android (to handle push by ourselves).

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing when I upgrade from 8.3.0 to 8.4.0, and I *never* use the notification field at all.  It seems the smoking gun is the "e=1" field in the notification, as this causes my 8.4.0 Bundles to contain a notification bundle that I don't think they should have, and I think this is what is causing things to go awry.Problem is, I can't for the life of me figure out what the "e=1" means, nor how to get rid of it, since when it exists, the GCM bundles never come to my code when my app isn't in the foreground.

Comment: Also we learned that if you have "content available" in push it will force to be shown automatically by system. You should remove it from Push message

Answer (score 4):

In your server just send the `e` field as `zero` inside the `notification` field.

```
{
    "to": "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
    "content_available": true,
    "notification": {
        "e": 0
    },
    "data": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

And then in android the bundle will be:

```
Bundle[{gcm.notification.e=0, key=value, ...}]
```

So now if your app is in background it will not show the notification by itself and will receive the bundle in your `GcmListenerService`.

But if you have both notification and data payloads and your app is in background, it will show the notification by itself, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

> **Hybrid messages with both notification and data payload**
>
> App behavior when receiving messages that include both notification and data payloads depends on whether the app is in the background, or the foreground —essentially, whether or not it is active at the time of receipt.
>
> - **When in the background**, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.
> - **When in the foreground**, your app receives a bundle with both payloads available.

Comment: Cool, very nice find!  As an undocumented feature, though, I'm still a little reluctant to use it in production.  If at some point in a future release, this *does* generate a notification on the client (as one might expect from the documentation if you have any kind of notification bundle in your JSON), then you might have some versions of your app that require this hack and some versions of your app that require you *don't* have this hack.  I have an open bug with Google on this issue and am trying to get some kind of an answer, even if it is just legitimizing this as a future-proof fix.

Comment: This does not work for me. A workaround is removing `notification` node for Android devices. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38741956/6371459