# Android notification is not showing it's content when app is not running

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Here is my interesting problem. Android notification that comes from GCM is not showing title and content (**just** shows App Name, and when click, open the MainActivity) when app is not running.

But when the app is open, it's showing **successfully** title and content. What can be the problem? It was running without problem and I didn't change anything.

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.package.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.package.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.package.xxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".Service.GcmService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

GcmService.java:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;
import com.package.xxx.Activity.ReadNormal;
import com.package.xxx.R;


public class GcmService extends GcmListenerService {

    public GcmService() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

        Log.d("GCMService", data.toString());

        String type = data.getString("type", "");

        if(type.equals("news")) {
           showNewsNotification(data);
        }

    }

    private void showNewsNotification(Bundle data) {

        String neId = data.getString("neId");

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(neId)) {
            return;
        }

        int id = Integer.valueOf(neId);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(data.getString("neTi"))
                .setContentText("Click to read more.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("neSi", data.getString("neSi"));
        i.putExtra("neUr", data.getString("neUr"));
        i.putExtra("neTi", data.getString("neTi"));
        i.putExtra("neIm", data.getString("neIm"));
        i.putExtra("neId", id);
        i.setClass(this, ReadNormal.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        /***/
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageSent(String msgId) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSendError(String msgId, String error) {
    }
```

Thank you.

Logs when app is running.

```
 D/GCMService: Bundle[{neId=4663755, neIm=http://icdn.posta.com.tr/editor/HD/30/1/2016/fft2mm7549077.jpg, neSi=Posta, neTi=Erdoğan: Rusya sonucuna katlanır, neUr=http://www.posta.com.tr/turkiye/HaberDetay/Erdogan--Rusya-sonucuna-katlanir.htm?ArticleID=324647, type=news, notification=Bundle[{e=1}], collapse_key=com.tekmobil.guncelhaber}]
```

Logs when app is NOT running.

```
(empty, there is no log)
```

Comment: Is there any error logs? can you provide us your logs?

Comment: There are no logs unfortunately. Very interesting.

Comment: Post the logs returned through the following line: `Log.d("GCMService", data.toString());` in both cases.

Comment: @OzgurGUL This is strange. Because if `data` is null. Then your app shouldn't be showing any notification at all.

Comment: @EricB. Yes, interesting issue.

Comment: Try logging the `type` variable in both cases.

Comment: There is no bundle coming in second case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the problem. I was using 8.4.0 version (up-to-date) of play services.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0' //GCM
```

I reduced the version to `8.3.0`. It works as expected.

Comment: this is definitely not a solution. Downgrading a version... I have similar problem i can see the content but no title.... please try to find a proper solution as oppose to this workaround .thanks

Comment: I'm still searching for a solution but this is apparently problem of version 8.4.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

try using

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 4):

In brief: try setting `content_available=false` when building the push on server side. The explanation follows.

This happens from version 8.4.0 of play services.
The documentation says that if you send a downstream message with both `data` and `notification` payload, the behavior changes if the App is in foreground or in background:

- in foreground the listener `onMessageReceived` is called and you can manually handle your notification
- in background the notification is automatically built by the system by taking `title` and `body` from the notification payload. If you don't specify them, the `title` is filled with application name and the `body` is left empty (and that's seems your case).

In your case I saw, in the message bundle, this strange thing `notification=Bundle[{e=1}]`
I encountered the same problem. This notification payload is self generated. I managed to remove it by setting `content_available=false` when building the push on server side. This is a problem if you are also working with iOS, but I didn't find any better solution...try it out.

Here the google doc I cited: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Hope it helps, bye

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is in this line:

you have not included this:

```
<service
            android:name="com.example.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lollipop changes this slightly by creating a small pop up at the top of the device window when a *Notification* is created.

Here's a Official documentation: [setFullScreenIntent](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean))

Using this method, you can create a new *Activity* with any custom layout you want and launch that instead of placing the *Notification* in the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the GCM 8.4.0 version, it is sending a notification payload even if you don't send it in your server.

```
notification=Bundle[{e=1}
```

But if you add this `e` field with value `zero` in your server it will work.

For more details se my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095326/2913510).