# what does gcm.notification.e=1 stand for, into push notification payload on Android?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm writing an Android application which receives downstream messages from a server using Google Cloud Messaging. When receiving a message with `onMessageReceived` I print the bundle and read this:

```
RECEIVED PUSH NOTIFICATION: Bundle[{gcm.notification.e=1, gcm.notification.badge=1, gcm.notification.sound=default, ..etc...
```

I don't understand the key **gcm.notification.e**  in the notification payload. On Google documentation I didn't find anything like that.
Moreover, when sending the message, I usually specify both a notification payload and a data payload. Now I tried to remove the notification payload but I still receive gcm.notification.e=1

Someone can help me understand this key and find a way to remove it? 
Thanks

EDIT: I found out that sending a message without the notification payload and with `content_available=false` (I set this to true when working with iOS) then the **`gcm.notification.e=1`** is not received. I receive only the data payload :). However, I still want to know the meaning of this `e`

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and it is breaking my notifications on Android altogether, because I use data only and expect it to *not* show up in the notification bar.  You're right that you can set content_available=false, but then it breaks the iOS app mechanism.  The only workaround I've found so far is to downgrade to Google Services version 8.3.0 instead of 8.4.0 until we get more info on this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490606 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059614

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this `e` field stands for `enable`. If you set it to `zero` in your server you won't receive the notification payload on Android. For more details se my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095326/2913510).