# Google Play Services 8.4.0 breaks Google Cloud Messaging for Android if iOS is also used

Tags: android, ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

There are several posts that describe aspects of this issue, but there hasn't yet been a satisfying answer, so I'm attempting to collate them all here in hopes of getting an authoritative answer that can address all of these issues.

[After updating Google play services to 8.4.0 push notifications displayed by themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490606)

[Android notification is not showing it's content when app is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059614)

[what does gcm.notification.e=1 stand for, into push notification payload on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360486)

The gist of the problem is that if you create a GCM message with data only (i.e. not using the notification field, and thus not intending for it to generate a notification) AND you include content_available=True (which is necessary to get the desired behavior from iOS clients), then since 8.4.0, this generates a undesirable blank notification in Android. *Prior to 8.4.0, everything worked just fine.*

The specifics of the problem seem to be that if the Android client receives a GCM field it doesn't understand, instead of just ignoring it, it adds an "e=1" field (presumably "e" means error?) as a notification *even if there was no notification in the message before*, causing it to trigger the code that makes a notification appear, rather than the code that directs it to the application to be handled.

Possible workaround: I imagine that one could keep track on the server of which clients were iOS and which clients were Android, and only include the content_available tag for the iOS clients, and this problem would be solved.  However, it wasn't necessary to do this in the past, and my system was built with the idea that I could be agnostic to the client types, as it seems was intended.

The fact that the content_available flag suddenly causes these blank notifications on Android seems like a bug that was newly introduced, but it would be very useful to know if it is in fact a bug that might be fixed in 8.5.0 (in which case I could just build with 8.3.0 for now until 8.5.0 comes out), or if it is intended to be a permanent solution.  If this is not going to change, is the correct solution to keep track of which GCM registration IDs belong to iOS devices and which belong to Android devices, and then to send out two separate GCM requests every time?

Thanks in advance for any official responses to this question from the Google team.

Comment: I think skimming through and posting at the [Android issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) is the best way to go.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks.  I didn't see anything related to this issue there, so I posted it as https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202960

Comment: Hm, that got immediately bounced as being the wrong forum:  "Sorry, this tracker is for issues with the Android OS only. Please use https://support.google.com/ to obtain support for Google products or services."  But unless I'm missing something, that really seems like a place for user support, not developer support.  Argh.

Comment: OK, I've finally tracked down what I think is the right place to file bugs like this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/support 
I'm going to file this one there and report back.

Comment: Sorry. This [link](https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support) should be the correct one.

Comment: Yep, that's where I filed it.  They've already responded and asked for more info, so it seems promising.  Will post with the answer once I've heard back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I finally got an acknowledgement from Google that this was in fact a bug, and that the fix was rolled out this week.  I can also confirm that the behavior I was seeing in 8.3.0 now works the same in 8.4.0, so apparently the fix was done entirely on the server side.

I was also advised that it is in fact best practices to partition your GCM messages on the server side between those going to iOS devices and those going to Android devices, as there may be times in the future where different payloads may be needed for the different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Se my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095326/2913510). The solution I found is to just send this `e` field with value `zero` on my server. For Android it worked, have not tested on iOS yet.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading version 9.2.1 [push notifications displayed by themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490606/after-updating-google-play-services-to-8-4-0-push-notifications-displayed-by-the) when application is in background (@dblank solution does not work for me)

**Workaround**: Remove the `notification` node for Android

```
{
    "to": "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
    "notification": {},  //Remove this node when PUSH to Android devices
    "data": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```